# CentOS8/RedHat8 - Disable AppStream modules when custom compiling?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, compile, centos-8

This is a general question regarding AppStream modules in CentOS/RedHat 8. If we are custom compiling apps such as Apache or PHP, should we disable the AppStream module for that app? I don't seem to be finding any direct reference to this in documentation. Is there any benefit and/or necessity? Thanks!

Comment: It isn't necessary to disable the AppStream module, as leaving it enabled wouldn't have any adverse effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create my own RPMs (just grab the source RPM, unpack and edit to taste; check any patches applied in the distribution's build for applicability). As long as your local version stays ahead of the distribution (you presumably want to base yours on newer upstream versions), regular updating won't touch your packages. Check out how to create your own repository, if you want several packages or just simplify the updating workflow.

Building pakages that can be installed alongside the official one is doable, but will require mucking around with e.g. global configuration file names/placing and binary names (perhaps including libraries part of the package).

But note that if you install non-distribution software builds, the standard open source guarantee applies: if it breaks, you get to keep the pieces.